# How to use a maven dependency in Kotlin REPL?

Tags: kotlin, read-eval-print-loop, kotlinc, kotlin-script, kotlin-repl

A Kotlin script with `*.main.kts` format can easily pull the dependency through the `@file:Repository` and `@file:DependsOn` annotations.

But I tried something similar with the REPL:

`kotlinc-jvm -cp <InstallationPath>/lib/kotlin-main-kts.jar`
(specified jar manually just because by default its not loaded)

```kotlin
import kotlin.script.experimental.dependencies.*  // just because they aren't imported automatically

@file:Repository("https://dl.bintray.com/<repo-path>")
@file:DependsOn("<dependency-notation>")

com.from.dependency.Class()
```

It throws: `error: unresolved reference: from`

Can we possibly use dependencies in REPL? If yes, how? I don't really want to specify the jars manually because if I were to, I'd need to download all its dependencies manually as well which is a terrible solution.

I guess there should be some tooling like `pip` for Kotlin REPL, that may make this process easier, and better if we don't really want to setup a whole project with gradle for some testing and stuffs.